# Transforming a Set Collection to an Array in Javascript is returning one less item

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, set

I'm developing a game project using HTML Canvas + Javascript.

Theres a Set Collection called entities, and it's inside a class called Level.

Then:

```
class Entity {
    constructor (name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Level {
    constructor () {
        this.entities = new Set([
            new Entity(),
            new Entity(), 
            new Entity(), 
        ]);
    }
}

const level = new Level();
```

However, when I do a for..of on this Set Collection, it simply ignores the last item.

It seems that when transforming from Set Collection to Array, it removes the last item from the list:

```
const entities = level.entities;
```

Output of `console.log(entities);`

[image]

Output of `console.log([...entities]);`

[image]

As you can see in the first image, the Set.size is equals to 6.

However, in the second image, the Array.length is equals to 5.

In other words, the last item was lost.

Can anyone who has gone through this be able to help?

Comment: Can you provide the code that you used to create the data in the images? As it is, your code works as expected.

Comment: @MichaelM. the full project is at GitHub (https://github.com/GustavoKimura/super-mario). The creation of the data shown in the images is separated into several files. However, I can post the complete Set Collection and Array here.

Comment: Why are you constructing a `Set` here?

Comment: It'd be helpful to create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to help debugging too.

Comment: @Unmitigated Because I want players and enemies entities to never be with same properties in the level.

Comment: @MichaelM. Can I reference a GitHub repository on any of these sites? So that it serves the project files automatically

Comment: @GustavoKimura Please don't do that. Instead, just copy the simplest code that replicates the issue.

Comment: @GustavoKimura `Set` does not achieve that with objects, though. For instance, `new Set([{a:1},{a:1}]).size` is `2`.